# Issue with selecting by PDO and printing out data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have function which selects data from MySQL database:

```
function  get_articles( $id ){
  global $pdo;
  $query = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT id_news, number, title, content
    FROM page_news
    WHERE number = :id
    ');
  $query->execute( array( ':id' => $id ) );
  return $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
}
```

Next, I am creating a new variable:

```
$articles = get_articles( $_GET['id'] );
```

If I `print_r($articles);` everything seems okay. Required table is printed:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id_news] => 226
        [number] => 14
        [title] => Cupcake ipsum dolor sit. Amet cotton candy I love I love bonbon.
        [content] => I love cotton candy I love sweet roll halvah cheesecake oat cake pastry halvah. Bonbon danish I love lemon drops chocolate candy canes jelly beans jelly-o. Tiramisu topping donut chocolate cake. Candy canes wafer icing cheesecake candy applicake tiramisu.
                     I love chocolate sugar plum chocolate bar. Jujubes wafer lollipop marshmallow halvah sesame snaps brownie icing sweet roll. 
    )
)
```

But when I am trying to echo any value with eg.:

```
echo "<p>{$articles->content}</p>";
```

nothing is being printed (an empty paragraph is created) and I cannot find out where the problem is.
I have another similar function which selects different data in the same way and printing out works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's array. You must use

```
echo "<p>{$articles[0]->content}</p>";
```

Comment: My mistake. It was so easy, but I was seeking very deep. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If your value in $articles is an array, you'll need to access that first object:

```
echo $articles[0]->content;
```